# Monospaced ascii editor

Tags: ascii, text-editor, monospace

Is there any ASCII "builder" / "text editor" or anything for that matter that will allow someone to write text differently then a normal text editor. The idea is that you take a monospaced font and fill in a textarea of some sort with all spaces and when you put your cursor anywhere on the text-area it "sticks". The next idea is that whenever you write a character it "eats" or replaces the existing character in that space. I can build this out in javascript fairly easily but I feel like it is a feature of some text editor out there. What are my options? Does this exist?

I hate when this happens when I don't want it to.

```
|----------------------------------------|
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                      s                  |
|                                \/      |
|                                        |
|----------------------------------------|
```

Rather then this...

```
|----------------------------------------|
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                      s                 |
|                                \/      |
|                                        |
|----------------------------------------|
```

Comment: You can just press the `Insert` key on your keyboard. Your regular text edit should eat characters instead of shifting them forward.

Comment: [insert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) and overtype are great words for this, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TheDraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TheDraw) is an old dos application wich does what you need.

I see on the Net more recent alternatives for windows, like [AcidDraw](http://download.cnet.com/ACiDDraw-ANSI-Editor/3000-2192_4-10005588.html) and [PabloDraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PabloDraw), but I do not know them.

Hope one of them is still useful.